# Строки и слова

Tags: delphi, строки

```
function IndexOfChar( S, ' ');
r:=s-IndexOfChar;
laststring:=сору(s,IndexOfChar,r)
EditN.Caption:=laststring;
```

Здесь мы копируем всю строку после символа (пробел). Как скопировать только второе слово? Т.е слово после пробела.

Comment: Ваш код неверный, откуда Вы его выдрали?

Comment: сам нахимичил))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если, я правильно понял, то нужно скопировать только второе слово из исходной строки, а слова разделяются пробелами, то вот код:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
Var
  SS, S: String;
begin
  SS:=Edit1.Text;

S:=Copy(SS, Pos(' ', SS)+1, Length(SS)-Pos(' ', SS));
  If (Pos(' ', S)>0) Then
    S:=Copy(S, 1, Pos(' ', S)-1);

Edit2.Text:=S;
end;
```

Comment: Зачем Вам переменная P типа Word ?
Почему Вы используете устаревшее POS вместо рекомендованного AnsiPos ?
Честно сложилось впечатление что выдрано с Интернета со старого ресурса, где еще рассматривается Delphi4

Comment: Переменную хотел использовать для сохранения позиции пробела, но только хотел. А функцию Pos всегда использую: привык уже, да про неё и в литературе всегда пишут. А, вот, про AnsiPos ничего пока не слышал.

Comment: Наверное не сильно свежие книги, [вот](http://delphibasics.ru/Pos.php) описание Вашей функции, и предупреждение почему не стоит ее использовать, а также ссылка на `AnsiPos`.

Comment: ну преимущество AnsiPos в том что она работает с кириллицей и этого преимущества вполне достаточно чтобы начать использовать эту функцию,но все сразу не схватишь на лету,по учебной программе к сожелению этой функции не встретишь..

Answer (score 0):

Вот мой вариант функции, которая возвращает нужное вам слово:

```
    Function WordFromIndex (s:string;I:integer):String;
    Var
      sl:TStringList;
    begin
      sl:=TstringList.Create;
      s:=StringReplace(s,#32,#13,[rfReplaceAll, rfIgnoreCase]);
      sl.Clear;
      sl.Text:=s;
      Result:=sl.Strings[i-1];
      sl.Free;
    end;
```

Использовать так:

```
   WordFromIndex (s,i);
```

Где `S` - это строка длинная, а `I` - номер слова в строке, результатом будет слово.

P.S. Сразу предупреждаю, писал просто так, многое не учтено.
Предполагается, что строка начинается не пробелом, что между словами строго один пробел и т.п.
Просто я показал еще один вариант решения задачи.